# Microsoft dynamic CRM DateTime field error

Tags: java, datetime, crm

I'm connecting to Dynamic CRM online using Java. I can create fields of any type but datetime. Whenever I add a DateTime field I get the following error.

*[ERROR] The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:entity. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 9875. 'EndElement' 'KeyValuePairOfstringanyType' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts' is not expected. Expecting element 'value'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.*

My code snippet is like this.

```
OrganizationServiceStub.DateTime d= new OrganizationServiceStub.DateTime();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
d.setDateTime(c);
collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(pair("startdate",d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use `OrganizationServiceStub.DateTime`. The stub that you are using provides `OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType` which allows you to pass any datatype values. We must know the type of field value and pass the particular type.

In your case to pass `Date`, the mircosoft crm sets as `GregorianCalendar` for date fields so we need to send of this type only. Below is the code,

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse("06/29/15");
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);

OrganizationServiceStub.AttributeCollection collection = new OrganizationServiceStub.AttributeCollection();
OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType dateattr = new OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
dateattr.setKey("startdate");
dateattr.setValue(date);
collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(dateattr);
```